# Element type "conditionalStyle" must be declared - error after adding new style

Tags: styles, jasper-reports

I added new style to my *jrtx* file:

```xml
<style name="BackgroundStyle" mode="Opaque" backcolor="gray">
  <conditionalStyle>
    <conditionExpression>Boolean.valueOf($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 == 0)</conditionExpression>
    <style backcolor="lightGray"/>
  </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

And in the report errors I see - **Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "conditionalStyle" must be declared.**

Help me to fix it, please

Answer (score 1):

The problem was constraint in Jasper not to use conditional style with Template option
Solution to use it in style direct not in template